# IE9 Only renders XSL on new tab/window

Tags: xml, internet-explorer-9

I have a server sending me a XML. IE8 Always renders it correctly while
IE9 only renders it once!

What I mean is that if I paste the URL into the address bar of a new tab, press enter, the page renders. I go back to the address bar, press enter, and I get the text contents of the XML. I do it again, and it renders!!!

So it works every other "enter" on address bar

```
the URL is :http://10.10.1.200/web/config/system-system-systemNumber.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/web/http/system-system-systemNumber.xsl"?>
<system-system-systemNumber>
  <system>
    <number>1</number>
    <device>
       <number>0</number>
    </device>
  </system>
</system-system-systemNumber>
```

When it fails, I don't even see IE9 trying to fetch the xsl file (watching in F12 network capture).

Comment: Can you load http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog_with_xsl.xml into your IE9 browser to see if you have the same issue? I cannot access your url, but the XSLT transformation of this url works fine in your IE9 browser.

Comment: check this out... a link I found here does the SAME!!!!

http://cynosuredev.com/CCDTest.xml

try it, open in IE9 or IE10, after the page renders, go up to the address bar, click in it, then press enter

Comment: I tried your link in IE9. The stylesheet never applies to the xml, no matter how many times I press enter in the address bar. I noticed that reference to stylesheet is http://cynosuredev.com/test.txt. I am not sure the .txt extension has anything to do with the IE not displaying the page correctly. Anyway, you did not tell me if the w3schools.com link works in your IE9 or not.

Comment: whats weird is, it does apply the stylesheet if I put the browser into ie8 mode... on another browser install, it detects it as ie8 document mode, and renders fine.  yes the w3link works fine... on 1st render, 2nd try fail, 3rd try works, every other fails!

Comment: more info, since I'm in control of the server code too... (java servlet) I added some debug when a .xsl file is requested...
on the 1st access to the url, say http://10.10.1.200/web/root/webControl.xml it tells me that the .xsl has been served to browser, but go back to address bar, click in it, press enter... IE9/10 does not request the .xsl and shows the xml as raw text, the more I see this, this has to be a browser bug... (or some cache issue??) if I put ie10 into BROWSER MODE: IE10 Compat view, it works correctly everytime